# How to recover jobs in Jenkins after port number change?

Tags: jenkins

I created Jenkins in default port 8080. After a week time some other organization level application takeover 8080 port now i am unable to connect to my jenkins.

So i thought of changing port number by running "`java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090`"

but when i connect using new port 9090,it says you can create new jobs and none of my existing jobs are being displayed.

I have created many jobs if i started again it will be rework. Is there any way to recover everything but port only changed?

Comment: Do you set JENKINS_HOME variable?

Comment: Is this installed on Windows or Linux? You can go to the `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/` directory and find all your jobs.